# Setting all vector values to zero from the point when a first negative value occurs in Matlab

Tags: matlab

I have a vector with random numbers:

```
x = [8,5,4,2,-1,-3,-4,2,3];
```

I would like to set all the vector values to zero, from the point when a first negative value occurs. Thus I would like to get the following result:

```
x = [8,5,4,2,0,0,0,0,0];
```

How do I go about achieving this?
Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
ind = find(x<0, 1, 'first')
x(ind:end) = 0;
```

Or put it all into one line

```
x(find(x<0, 1, 'first'):end)= 0;
```

Another way

```
x(cumsum(x<0)>0) = 0;
```

Comment: The `cumsum` approach seems to be the fastest for vectors smaller than ~4000 elements! +1, nice =)

Answer (score 3):

Do `x(find(x<0,1):end) = 0`. First, you get the index i of the first element that is smaller than zero, using `find`. Then you assign 0 to all indexes i up to the the end of the array.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a possible solution:

```
>> [m,idx]=max(x<0);
>> y = x;
>> y(idx:end)=0
y =

   8   5   4   2   0   0   0   0   0
```